# Content Security Policy directive: "frame-src 'self' data:"

Tags: reactjs, content-security-policy, react-quill

I have an app, in which the user would be able to copy an image URL, paste it unto an input and the image will be loaded on a box.

> vendors.fbdee1b68a2292d6de96.chunk.js:2 Refused to frame 'https://www.youtube.com/' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-src 'self' data:".

[image]

I tried some codes;

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="frame-src 'self' data: https://www.youtube.com">
```

- 

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="frame-src 'self' data: *">
```

but did not work. What can I do about it?